# Specify max number of databases a user can own

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

Is this possible?

I would like to have a limit for a user, lets say 5 databases.

So when he tries to issue a CREATE query to create a 6th an exception is thrown.

Comment: I'd guess there's something you could do with the Policy-based management features, even if it's only a daily check to see if someone's exceeded the rule. I'm not familiar with that subsystem, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot do this - at least not in a declarative way (just simply specify the max number of databases owned for each user).

The closest you could get with standard SQL Server functionality would be to create a DDL trigger for `CREATE DATABASE` and in that trigger, check to see if the current user already owns five databases, and in that case, let the trigger fail the operation.

Something along the lines of this (taken from [TechNet sample](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186406.aspx)):

```
CREATE TRIGGER ddl_trig_database 
ON ALL SERVER 
FOR CREATE_DATABASE 
AS 
    -- here, check to see if current user already owns five databases
    -- and if so, fail the trigger by using RAISERROR
GO
```

Comment: What about if/when they run sp_changeDBOwner?

Comment: @Philip Kelley: well, in that case, you might have to trap yet some more DDL operations.... as I said - it could get pretty messy, and there's no easy, "out-of-the-box", declarative way to do this...

Answer (score 1):

look into DDL triggers, with a trigger like this one below you can trap the CREATE DATABASE  statement

```
CREATE TRIGGER ddl_trig_database 
ON ALL SERVER 
FOR CREATE_DATABASE 
AS 
    --do something here
    -- select count(*)from sys.sysdatabases where sid = ???
GO
```